# Sufficient conditions for positive definitness of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

are there theorems similar to "if a symmetric real matrix is diagonally dominant then it is (semi-)positive definite"?
Maybe, something like "if
$2|a_{i i}| \geq \sum\limits_{j\neq i} |a_{ij}|$ for all $i$ and the number of zeros in the $i$-th row is $\geq $ something, then $A = (a_{ij})_{i,j}$ is positive definite"?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your definition of "positive definite"? The usual definition require the matrix to be symmetric. Real symmetric matrices are Hermitian and hence their eigenvalues are real. If a real symmetric matrix is (strict-)diagonal dominant, then it is (semi-)positive definite (as a corollary of 
[Gershgorin circle theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem)).

Comment: More context is needed here. Why are you looking for such results? To me it sounds like an XY problem.